# How to output a csv file for more than one list?

Tags: python

The following code allows me to print a CSV output with the first "column" for the word and the second for the frequency. However, I have a second list called B that should be output in the same file.

```
A=[food:2,wine:1,dog:5]
B=[cat:3,bird:2]
```

```
cnt=Counter(A)
with open("list.csv", encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as fp:
    fp.write('Word:Frequency\n')  
    for tag, count in cnt.items():  
        fp.write('{}:{}\n'.format(tag, count))
```

The final result should be

```
 1. Word:Frequency:Word2:Frequency2
 2. food:2:cat:3
 3. wine:1:bird:2
 4. dog:5
```

Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: Have a look into the `zip` function.  This can be used to iterate two objects at once.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `itertools.zip_longest()` since one of the dictionaries is shorter than the other.

Comment: Those aren't lists. They look like dictionaries, but dictionaries are surrounded by `{}`, not `[]`.

Comment: Please make the code in your question valid executable code, with imports and _everything_ needed to run it. This is called a [mre].

Comment: They actually look like the result of `Counter()`, not the to it.

Comment: If you're going to write a "csv" file then instead of writing the file yourself as your current code does you really should use the `csv` library module - there are usage examples in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.zip_longest()` to pair up two sequences, and add filler when one is shorter than the other. You can fill with an empty tuple, so those columns will be omitted when you combine the two tuples.

Use the `csv` module to convert these combined tuples to rows in the file.

```
from collections import Counter
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

cnt1 = Counter(A)
cnt2 = Counter(B)
with open("list.csv", encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as fp:
    csv_out = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=':')
    csv_out.writerow(['Word', 'Freq', 'Word2', 'Freq2'])
    for v1, v2 in zip_longest(cnt1.items(), cnt2.items(), fillvalue=tuple()):
        csv_out.writerow(v1 + v2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used your code adding a parenthesis that was missing after tuple(), but I receive an error message: TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Comment: I forgot to call `items`.

Comment: Just one last question: is it possible to print : even if there are no values? Let's say I have A=({dog:5})
B=({cat:3,bird:2}) - in this case I risk to have bird:2 print under the first word:frequency

Comment: `if v1 == (): v1 = ('', '')`